# Object life after death (retain count = 0)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I just noticed this in some code that's been working for months. Though it makes me curious I'm sure we've been living on borrowed time...

Assuming **activeItem**:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) ItemView *activeItem;
```

And we have this conditional in touchesEnded:

```
if (CGRectContainsPoint(dropRect, touchLocation)) {
    ItemView *replacementItem = [[ItemView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    [newItems replaceObjectAtIndex:[newItems indexOfObject:activeItem] withObject:replacementItem];

    [self addSubview:replacementItem];
    [controller.view.subView addItem:activeItem];
    [replacementItem goCenter];
    [replacementItem release];
}
```

The only thing that's retaining **activeItem** is the NSArray, `newItems`. Should I retain it before the call to `replaceObjectAtIndex` and then release it when I release `replacementItem`? Another way?

Seems to be working fine but isn't it only a matter of time before EXC_BAD_ACCESS?!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that somewhere you have `activeItem = something` instead of `self.activeItem = something`

The difference is that the "self" dot version goes through the synthesized mutator (setter) method which would perform a retain before assigning to the ivar. This assumes that you have a synthesized method or a manually constructed one that does what the property claims it will.

It may not be making any difference though since you may just be using this as a weak reference. If you really do want a weak reference you might want to change that retain to assign and read up on the Objective-C conventions for weak references.

(In this case it looks like you're using `activeItem` more like an index into something rather than a "container" designed to "own" the object, and this makes it a scenario for weak references IF that is what you're intending it for.)

Comment: Figured it out...your post got me thinking. it was still being retained by the view...

Comment: Also, no weak references (yet) on the iPhone (since there's no GC either...)

Comment: Kendall Helmstetter Gelner: You can have a weak (that is, non-retaining) reference without GC. The `__weak` *keyword* is only for GC.

Comment: Yes of course, using an assign property - but I thought the original poster was referring to __weak as usually the term is only used in conjunction with __weak (at least I've never heard it used otherwise for Objective-C).  I think I misread his point on that...

Comment: I wasn't talking about __weak. I've never used GC in Objective-C since I've only ever done cocoa-touch, no cocoa, development, but really any time you have a reference that's not supposed to "own" an object and manage its reference count it can be considered a weak reference. It's just that garbage collectors have to be specifically told about them. Seems like a reasonable thing to do for a non-GC weak ref would be declare a property with an accessor that will return nil if the reference is no longer valid.